# To take snapshot of SCNView fail with Swift on iPhone 6 Plus / 6S Plus

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, scenekit

SceneKit provides a method `snapshot()` for rendering `SCNView` into image object.
I write the following code:

```
let imageWidth = 512
let nativeScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeScale
let viewSize = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(imageWidth) / nativeScale, <any height> / nativeScale)
let sceneView = SCNView(frame: viewSize)
sceneView.backgroundColor = .clearColor()
let scene = SCNScene()

//... Add something node to scene

sceneView.scene = scene

let image: UIImage? = sceneView.snapshot()
```

This code can obtain image in Simulator.
And, `image` has data in iPhone 6/6S or less.

But, when I run in **iPhone 6 Plus or iPhone 6S Plus**, the console shows me the error:

```
<Error>: 
CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination:
    8 integer bits/component;
    32 bits/pixel;
    RGB color space model; kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast;
    2047 bytes/row.
Valid parameters for RGB color space model are:
    16  bits per pixel,      5  bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst
    32  bits per pixel,      8  bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst
    32  bits per pixel,      8  bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast
    32  bits per pixel,      8  bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst
    32  bits per pixel,      8  bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
    64  bits per pixel,      16 bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
    64  bits per pixel,      16 bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast
    128 bits per pixel,      32 bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast |kCGBitmapFloatComponents
    128 bits per pixel,      32 bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast |kCGBitmapFloatComponents
See Quartz 2D Programming Guide (available online) for more information.
```

After that, I use the loop:

```
for imageWidth in 1...1100
```

`image` will be nil when `imageWidth` is following values:

```
(power of 2), 49, 97, 98, 113, 179, 181, 211, 226, 241, 343, 347, 358, 373, 377,
388, 403, 407, 422, 437, 452, 467, 482, 497, 501, 671, 679, 686, 694, 701, 709,
716, 724, 746, 761, 776, 784, 791, 799, 806, 814, 821, 829, 844, 859, 874, 889,
904, 949, 964, 979, 994, 1002, 1009, 1017
```

What is this sorcery!?

Comment: Sounds like a possible bug. [Have you filed one with Apple?](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: Yes, I reported the issue to Apple Bug Reporter.